# Getting link with music playlist on it to display as a playlist within the Facebook newsfeed, leveraging Facebook open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-opengraph, audio

I've tried to configure the Facebook metadata on my webpage to have the necessary music.playlist og tags, with the hope that when posting a link to the webpage on Facebook it would appear as a playlist in peoples newsfeeds as it does for Spotify, Rdio and a few other websites (like this: http://oi41.tinypic.com/f0t0s4.jpg), instead of as a link.

Using the Facebook URL Linter, the following metadata is shown to be scrapped by Facebook for this webpage http://mvm.fm/19408:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="20 tracks featuring Bob Marley." />
<meta property="og:title" content="Is This Love" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://img.youtube.com/vi/CHekNnySAfM/hqdefault.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Music Video Machine" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="329359117170530" />
<meta property="og:type" content="music.playlist" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge" />
<meta property="music:creator" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/user/paulme" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/1" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="1" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/2" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="2" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/3" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="3" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/4" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="4" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/5" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="5" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/6" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="6" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/7" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="7" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/8" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="8" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/9" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="9" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/10" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="10" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/11" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="11" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/12" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="12" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/13" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="13" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/14" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="14" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/15" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="15" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/16" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="16" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/17" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="17" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/18" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="18" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/19" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="19" />
<meta property="music:song" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/20" />
<meta property="music:song:track" content="20" />
```

For one of the "music:song" urls (http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/8) used in the metadata above, the following is scraped:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="&#x266b; By Bob Marley.(4:43)" />
<meta property="og:title" content="I Shot The Sheriff" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://img.youtube.com/vi/2XiYUYcpsT4/hqdefault.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Music Video Machine" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="329359117170530" />
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/8" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.musicvideomachine.com/19408/track/8" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge" />
<meta property="music:duration" content="283" />
```

When I share http://mvm.fm/19408 to Facebook though it just appears as a link with a description and image like this: http://oi40.tinypic.com/acgcg7.jpg

Is my meta data missing something, do I need to register my Facebook app in a different way, or submit the playlist webpages ahead of time to Facebook before they are shared? Or is something else missing? Once again, I want to get http://mvm.fm/19408 to appear as a playlist, with links out to the tracks, when posted onto a newsfeed on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your specification of the playlist does not adhere to the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/music.playlist/ I haven't tried it myself, but I guess you need to place each song in the og:audio or og:video arrays as described in the page linked above.

Maybe the playlist also needs to be published first as stated on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/ in the "Playlists" paragraph.